# kNN state-of-the-art implementation

Tags: machine-learning, implementation, knn

I am looking for a kNN implementation package.

This package should:

- deal with multi-label problem
- give a detailed output, what are those k nearest neiboneighbors points 
  that classify the test point.
- Implement all kinds of distance metrics.
- Implement all kind of instance weighting.

So far, I have not found one (WEKA doesn't support multi-labeling).

Comment: When saying "multi-labeling" - you mean that each sample has multiple labels with weights? E.g. sample `x` is 70% related to class A and 30% related to class B?

Comment: yes multiple labels, but no weight, for example, sample x is A and B, x1 just A, x3 - C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Mulan for Multi label knn. In Mulan it is called MLKNN. A detailed link to start with knn in Mulan can be found [here](http://mulan.sourceforge.net/starting.html)